# Database of Cars in Qatar

Tags: cars, database

Seeking a database of all cars in Qatar, by *name of car manufacturer* and *model* (make/model). Any other data is helpful, particularly a tentative price list, but not required.

Comment: Do you want a list of *available* cars only, or do you (also) want to know how many of them are in use?

Answer (score 2):

It seems as though right now, Qatar has open data policies in place, but are still fulfilling them on a case by case basis. They have explicitly stated on this site here: http://www.ictqatar.qa/en/qatar-digital-government/open-government/open-data the benefits of open data, and the type of data sets each department in Qatar will be fulfilling.

If I had to guess (or hope rather), they are in the process of building a searchable open data portable with actively uploaded data sets. I would think you should be able to  request the data you are looking for on the same site link, but who knows how long it will take for them to fulfill their request. Hope that helps!

***Full Disclosure: I work at [Datazar](https://www.datazar.com/) (A collaborative open data libraryfor all sources)***